# unable to modify flow in Apache NiFi 1.14.0 in HTTP mode

Tags: apache-nifi

I understand that the official documentation recommends using NiFi with HTTPS, but it nonetheless contains a word for using NiFi under HTTP, like the `nifi.web.http.port` property.

Also, I'd like to incrementally incorporate and evolve the NiFi instance into our's current data infrastructure, starting with non-critical data pipelines. So, the TLS layer right now is not necessary and could add friction during the deployment phase. So, I decide to go on the HTTP path.

After changing some settings, I am able to access NiFi's GUI at `http://localhost:8080/nifi` but I find out that I cannot make any change to the Flow. Write operations, i.e `POST` / `PUT` / `DELETE` requests, are rejected by `HTTP 403`.

NiFi doc says:

[image]

And by monitoring the API traffic between the GUI and NiFi instance, I can confirm that the `PermissionsEntity` has both `canRead:true` and `canWrite:true`.

I used a containerized NiFi instance.

Has anyone also encounter similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root canvas may have been set for the default single-user that NiFi 1.14 generates if it starts up without security configuration.

First thing to try is right-clicking on the canvas and granting yourself access if you can.

The second option: try (re)moving the flow.xml.gz, users.xml and authorizations.xml and then restarting Nifi. New files will be generated that may work better with anonymous access.

Either way, setting up security now will probably mean less friction down the road, not more. I strongly advise you to bite the bullet and get it set up securely.